# synchronization of position in different watch

Tags: c, algorithm

I have tried to solve the following problem unsuccessfully:

You are given 16 clocks, all set at some position between 1 and 12. The initial configuration is:

```
12, 9, 3, 12, 6, 6, 9, 3, 12, 9, 12, 9, 12, 12, 6, 6
```

You are given a set of switch lines:

```
# define max_switch 10

int switchLines[max_switch][5] =
{
    {0,1,2,-1,-1},
    {3,7,9,11,-1},
    {4,10,14,15,-1},
    {0,4,5,6,7},
    {6,7,8,10,12},
    {0,2,14,15,-1},
    {3,14,15,-1,-1},
    {4,5,7,14,15},
    {1,2,3,4,5},
    {3,4,5,9,13}
};
```

Entries equal to -1 are ignored. When you press a switch, the value of the clocks listed in the switch line increases by 3.

For example pressing the first switch in the initial configuration would yield:

```
3, 12, 6, 12, 6, 6, 9, 3, 12, 9, 12, 9, 12, 12, 6, 6
```

You are allowed to press any switch any number of time in any order.

What is the minimum number of switch presses needed to set all the clocks to 12 ?

I am looking for an algorithm to solve the above problem.

Below is the solution I am trying

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int clock1[16] ={12, 9, 3, 12 ,6, 6 ,9 ,3 ,12, 9, 12, 9 ,12 ,12, 6 ,6};
int swicthApplied = 0;
#define mac_sw 10

int switchLink[mac_sw][5]=
{
    {0,1,2,-1,-1},
    {3,7,9,11,-1},
    {4,10,14,15,-1},
    {0,4,5,6,7},
    {6,7,8,10,12},
    {0,2,14,15,-1},
    {3,14,15,-1,-1},
    {4,5,7,14,15},
    {1,2,3,4,5},
    {3,4,5,9,13}
};

int isSwicthRequired()
{

int i=0, need = 0;

for(i=0;i<16;i++)
{
    if(clock1[i] <  12)
    {
        need = 1;

    }

}
return need;
 }

 int findmax(int array[], int size)
 {

int   maximum, c, location = 0;

maximum = array[0];
if(array[0] == 0) location = -2;
for (c = 1; c < size; c++)
{
    if (array[c] > maximum)
    {
        maximum  = array[c];
        location = c  ;
    }
}
return location +1;
}

runSwicth(int pos)
{

int i =0;

for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    int valu = switchLink[pos][i];

    if(valu == -1 ) continue;
    if(clock1 [valu] == 12)
    {
         // continue;
         clock1 [valu] = 3;
    }
    else
        clock1 [valu] = clock1[valu] +  3;
 }

 printClock(clock1,16);
 swicthApplied = 1 + swicthApplied;
//exit(0);
}

int findBestMatchSwitch( void)
{
//if(maxSwicth >=10) return -1;
 int maxSwicth = mac_sw,numberofSwicths = 5,i,j;

 int array[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

for( i = 0;i<maxSwicth;i++)
{

    for(j=0;j<numberofSwicths;j++)
    {

        int pos = switchLink[i][j] ;
        if(pos == -1) continue;
        if(clock1[pos] != 12)
        {
            array[i] = array[i] +1;
        }
    }
}

int loc = findmax(array,10);
if(loc == -1) return -1;
applySwicth(loc -1);
//omitLoc[loc-1] = -1;
return 0;
//exit(0);
}



 int runAlignment()
{

int need =0;
while(1)
{
    need = isSwicthRequired();
    if (need ==0) break;
    if(findBestMatchSwitch() == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

}
return need;
}




 int main(void) {

runAlignment();
printf("Swicthes Required [%d]",swicthApplied);
//getClockneed();
//printClock(clockNeed,16);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Please state your problem more clearly. Is it about the logic of applying switches or about programming the actual solution, given some logic?

Comment: For the logic part you may want to look into the knapsack problem. There should be a way to align your problem to it.

Comment: I require a solution to to find out  minimum number of switches line required to align all the clocks to 12 ..  If I can get a help for logic I can program ..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a code-for-me service. Post your efforts and we can give you help.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a solution is a list of switches of minimum length such that, when the switches are pressed in sequence, the initial configuration is transformed into the desired one.

Note that the order in which the switches are pressed doesn't actually matter. Note also that in a minimal solution no switch is pressed more than three times.

Hence for each of ten switches, you have four choices (0 to 3 presses) to consider, i.e. the total number of possibilities to examine is 4^10 or about a million.

Comment: "A solution is a list of switches of minimum length that,  ." I did not understand this .. All switches are of same length ..  What do you exactly referred here as length ..

Comment: If I try all the switches in sequences solution order will be more .. Execution time limited was 30sec . I need to find out how many switch line I would require ..  example if given clock is {12, 6 ,6 ,6 ,6 ,6, 12, 12, 12 ,12 ,12, 12, 12 ,12, 12 ,12}; and if I apply SwicthLine[8] i.e [1,2,3,4,5] 2 times then my clock will be aligned .. so answer would be 2 ..

Comment: I updated the code which am trying .. I did not get exactly on the section "   candidates_next = []
    for i = 0 to MAX_SWITCH - 1
        for each x in candidates
            c = x"       Can you please help to understand your sudo code more

Comment: one more doubt I have in the algorithm , we need to apply all switches in a each line .. but from the algorithm we concatenate one by one rite?.. if you see my program, I have given with switchLink which is 10X5 array .. so 10 switch line and 5 switches in each .. so if I apply any switch line, all switches in the line will change the clock ..  I think am facing difficulty to write in C .. Please help to convert your algorithm to C

Comment: Talking about optimization now? Looking at the maximum of 16 clocks with 4 states each, there is room for some fancy bit-logic where each clock is represented with 2 bit and the whole configuration in a single 32 bit unsigned. The switches can also be converted to 32 bit values, having a `01` at each designated switch position. State `x` and switch `s` can then be used to create the new state `y` as `y = x ^ s ^ ((x << 1) & (s << 1))` ... I just hope I didn't overlook some corner case here^^. Final transition result has bit 1 at each position.

Comment: @AntoineMathys Since the requirement is 30sec execution time limit, low level optimization is obviously pointless for the original question. It's just an idea for *as fast as possible computation* after applying all algorithmic optimizations.